# Querying multiple tables in TSQL where table name comes from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I need to select from table where the the table name suffix are from another table, like this :

```
declare @value  nvarchar(3),
@table nvarchar(1000),
@SQLST NVARCHAR(255);

set  @value = N'select column1 from tableX';

EXEC @value

set @table ='partoftableY'

Set @SQLST ='select * from' +@tabel + @value -- here I create the table name
```

However there are multiple values in  TableX (0-999) and so this doesn't work. Do I need a For Each type construct.

Comment: There are two way to do this - and you may not need to do a for-each (called a cursor) - it might be possible in a set operation. Please tell us what you are doing with the results and we'll see what's the best solution.

Comment: Hi, well at the end i need to gather all the tables into one.For example: the result will be ten tables

Answer (score 1):

here in an example I created with two tables (partoftableY1 & partoftableY2) with different data in each

```
/*

create table tableX (column1 int);

insert into tablex 
          select 1
union all select 2;

create table partoftableY1 (data nvarchar(50));
create table partoftableY2 (data nvarchar(50));

insert into partoftableY1 select 'hey 1 here';
insert into partoftableY2 select 'hey 2 here';

*/


declare @sql nvarchar(max)

-- use the ability of SQL to build up string of all the sql you need to run

set @sql = 'select data from (select '''' as data'

select @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ' union all ', '') 
               + 'select data from partoftableY' 
               + cast(column1 as nvarchar(4)) from tableX
select @sql = @sql + ') X where data <>'''''

-- DEBUG for seeing what SQL you created
print @sql

-- Now execute the SQL
exec sp_executesql @sql= @sql
```

which gives me the results of

```
hey 1 here
hey 2 here
```

**You will need to adjust it for types of your data, but this should give you the main idea**

For reference here is the sql that was created and executed:

```
select data 
from  (
                select '' as data 
      union all select data from partoftableY1 
      union all select data from partoftableY2
     ) X 
where data <>''
```

*N.B.*

- I put formatted it for easier reading, as it's actually created as one long line
- I used selet data and not select * as the number of columns needs to be the same for each select in the union. You will need to select the columns you need and then make changes ensure that all the columns in the selects in  the union are the same.
- There is a dummy select at the top of the union to make the union code easy - no conditionals needed as whether the union all needs to present
- I used the out select over the whole union to enable you to get sid of the dummy select

Comment: Thank you :) i think i get the idea.The result(all the table that exists) will be all the joins in one table.

Comment: yes, but you need to be careful and put check code in to ensure you avoid duplicates from table ex. And other errors like there being data in tablex but the other table not existing etc....

Comment: Other thing, what did you mean on data? the columns to select?Thank you

Comment: So...i have to see if the table exists and then begin the cicle to get the union of all the tables in one table.

Comment: And remember if the data will be mutually exclusive, UNION ALL is faster

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @SQLST NVARCHAR(max)='';

DECLARE @select nvarchar(max)=N'select * from partoftableY'

DECLARE @union nvarchar(max)=N'
UNION ALL
'
SELECT @SQLST=@select+column1+@union
FROM tablex

SELECT @SQLST=substring(@SQLST,1,LEN(@SQLST)-11)

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLST
```

Comment: partoftableY is a part of a table example : there are multiple tables like customerY,custormerX,customerZ,customerA. So i'm trying to search customer + @a where @a contains(Y,Z,X,A) and this @a is resulted from a select from other table (names)